# How to IMPORT or ADD and COMMIT UNVERSIONED COPY to Subversion using SVNAnt in Hudson?

Tags: svn, hudson, svnant

We are running Hudson ver.  1.395 as CI server and StarTeam as Repository. We are planning to move to Subversion as Repository(Hudson Server Plugin 2.3.3 installed). There is no issue in checking out from SVN server using SVNAnt (ver 1.3.1)script in Hudson, however we can’t  IMPORT or ADD and COMMIT UNVERSIONED COPY to SVN.

```
<project name="***">        
    …   
    <path id="svn.classpath">
        <!--pathelement location="${svn.lib}/svnant.jar"/-->
        <fileset dir="${svn.lib}">
            <include name="svnant.jar"/>
            <include name="ganymed.jar"/>
            <include name="jna.jar"/>
            <include name="svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
            <include name="svnjavahl.jar"/>
            <include name="svnkit.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path> 

    <!-- Load the SVN Task -->
    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svn.classpath" />

    <!-- SVN Checkout -->
    <target name="svn-checkout">
        <svn username="${svn-user}" password="${svn-password}" svnkit="true" javahl="false">
            <checkout url="${svn-url}" revision="HEAD" destPath="${env.WORKSPACE}" />
            <info target="${env.WORKSPACE}"/>
        </svn>
    </target>

    <!-- SVN Add & Commit -->   
    <target name="svn-add">
        <svn username="${svn-user}" password="${svn-password}" svnkit="true" javahl="false">
            <add dir="${env.WORKSPACE}" force="true"/>
            <info target="${env.WORKSPACE}"/>
        </svn>
    </target>

    <target name="svn-commit">  
        <svn username="${svn-user}" password="${svn-password}" svnkit="true" javahl="false">
            <commit dir="${env.WORKSPACE}" message="${svn.message}"/>
            <info target="${env.WORKSPACE}"/>
        </svn>
    </target>
```

![Commit-Output][1]
However we can do all the task of checkout, add, commit, import unversioned or underversioned copy using TortoiseSVN(1.7.11) or command line and ant script using CollabNer Subverison Client(1.7.8).
I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <svn verbose="true" refid="svn.settings">
        <add dir="${svn_folder}" force="true" recurse="true" />
        <commit dir="${svn_folder}" message="${version}"/>
    </svn>
```

Comment: Thank you FoxyBOA for the quick reply. The build is success if I add and commit back same copy of svn checkout. But when I add new folder which is unversioned copy and commit the workspace, the build is unsuccessful.  I simply added a new folder as:                   
<target name="modify" >
<mkdir dir="${workspace}\New Folder"/>
</target>
Then add-Commit. Still have isssue. Please Help!

Comment: please put your exception into the original question